# How to change pixels in an image?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I want to make changes to the pixels, but the pixels in the new image file are different from the pixels I've changed.

When I check the cycles one by one, the pixels change correctly, but when I create the new picture, it's different.

How can I solve the problem?

```py
def str2bin(data): 
        strbin = []  

        for i in data: 
            strbin.append(format(ord(data), '08b')) 
        return strbin 

def hide_str(img, data):
    datalist = str2bin(data)
    lendata = len(datalist)

    h, w, ch = 0, 0, 0

    for i in range(lendata):
        for j in range(0, 8):
            if ch > 2:
                ch = 0
                w += 1

            val = img[h, w]

            if (datalist[i][j] == '0') & ( val[ch] % 2 != 0):
                val[ch] -= 1

            if (datalist[i][j] == '1') & ( val[ch] % 2 == 0):
                val[ch] += 1

            ch += 1

            img[h, w] = tuple(val)

    return img
```

Example my string is = `"T"` and my string binary = `"01010100"`:

```
img = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
img[0, 0] output [0, 0, 0]
cv2.imwrite("image2.jpg", hide_str(img, str))
img2 = cv2.imread("image2.jpg")
img2[0, 0] output [0, 9, 0]
```

Other pixels are the same as I want.

Comment: What is `str2bin()`? It's not a function in the `cv2` module.

Comment: I wrote to convert the string to binary.

Comment: What is the format of the data it is returning? You really need to [edit] your question and add the code for the `str2bin()` function to make it more of a [mcve]—if you want help, that is.

Comment: It's also unclear what you meant by "my string is = `"T"` and my string binary = `"01010100"`". What does that have to do with the code in your question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a new member and I'm making the necessary arrangements now

Comment: No problem—some guidelines for posting questions here are explained in [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Anyway, the `str2bin()` function looks like it may be a significant part of it the problem. When I have a chance I'll look into it...or someone else will.

Comment: I can't test it but the line `strbin.append(format(data, '08b'))` is always formatting the same value, `data`, each iteration of the loop. I think it should be something like `strbin.append(format(i, '08b'))` or maybe `strbin.append(format(ord(i), '08b'))`. Giving a variable the same name as the function it is in is a little confusing (Python isn't Visual Basic).

Comment: I want to test the steganography and i have to convert characters to binary. This is the way I use the ready function I use. It works properly when I test this function.

Comment: I change modul and solved. Change OpenCV to Pillow